# Websocket doesn't work in server 127.0.0.1:8000

Tags: symfony, websocket, phpwebsocket

I'm using [Gos Web Socket Bundle](https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle) in Symfony and I try to work in [demo they give](https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebsocketAppDemo). I'm very confuse about the port because the it works, if the port is `127.0.0.1:1337` but when I run the server of symfony it generate `127.0.0.1:8000`, so I try to add it here'

```
gos_web_socket:
    server:
        port: 8000       #The port the socket server will listen on
        host: 127.0.0.1   #The host ip to bind to
        router:
            resources:
                - '@AppBundle/Resources/config/pubsub/routing.yml'
```

and the websocket in javascript

```
 var websocket = WS.connect("ws://127.0.0.1:8000");
```

When the time I display it in my page. I always get bad request. But If I use `WS.connect("ws://127.0.0.1:1337");` it works, and the server I run from symfony is `127.0.0.1:8000`. I'll be glad if you explain the reason why I need to use 1337 port than 8000

Comment: You are not forced to use port 1337, just a port that is open in the server and/or firewall; maybe port 8000 is not open.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the port 8000 is already occupied with some other service. I would be suspicious of PHP builtin server, so check the port which is the server listening on by `php bin/console server:status`. If the port is 8000, then stop it `php bin/console server:stop` and start on some other port `php bin/console server:start 127.0.0.1:8000` and the websocket shoud then be available on 8000.

Comment: I try this one `php bin/console server:status 127.0.0.1:8080`. the result is `No web server is listening on http://127.0.0.1:8080`.  so I setup the websocket to 8080 then. when the time I run `php app/console gos:websocket:server` and refresh my page. I got bad request result

Comment: What if you access the `http://127.0.0.1:port/app_dev.php/app/example` via browser, does it work?

Comment: It shows the page but I got this error all the time `WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8080/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response`

Comment: So when you run `php bin/console gos:websocket:server` does it show `Starting Gos WebSocket
Launching Ratchet WS Server on: 127.0.0.1:8080` in the console?

Comment: yes. but if add the port `var websocket = WS.connect("ws://127.0.0.1:8080")` this will not work

Comment: OK then, seems like the server is running o.k. on the port 8080 (checked by console message `Launching Ratchet WS Server on: 127.0.0.1:8080` and command `php bin/console server:status 127.0.0.1:8080`), so the next what I would check connection between client/server. Is there any virtualization used? Or, pls, describe the environment.